# One-liner to determine who wins in Rock, Paper, Scissors

Tags: c

So I am writing a simple Rock, Paper, Scissors game in C (it's for an assignment by the way, though the main thing is to learn sockets.  Also, I suspect it will be due before I get a good answer).  I have it setup as Rock=0, Paper=1, and Scissors=2.  Is there an easy one-liner to determine who wins?  I tried playing around with it on paper, but I couldn't figure out any patterns.

Comment: If this question doesn't concern the sockets part of the assignment, it could easily be converted into a `[code-golf]`.

Comment: 6 minutes to a good answer, when's your assignment due?

Comment: Just as a note, I generally would assign those values (rock, paper, scissors, dynamite) to strings or characters.  In general it is bad practice to make them a number because logically you will never want to add them.  This is not important for assignment problems but good to get in the habit so when you have bigger problems they don't kick your ass.

Comment: @sixtyfootersdude: enum constants are very useful even if you're not doing arithmetic on them.  Strings can be problematic because typos in them won't be caught at compilation time.

Comment: @sixtyfootersdude: I disagree. Computers are much better at handling integers than strings. I mean, simply look at any decent API: Here integer constants are used virtually anywhere. For example we have WM_COMMAND, WM_KEYDOWN... all being integer constants, even though it would never make sense to compute WM_KEYDOWN + WM_COMMAND (for example). The system would be so much slower if the message IDs were strings ("keydown" etc.). I do not know much C++, but in Delphi you could write TGameChoice = (gcRock, gcPaper, gcScissors), which would effectively create integer constants equal to 0, 1, and 2.

Comment: @sixtyfootersdude: but the point is that I *do* want to logically manipulate them with some one-liner that gives the correct answer.

On the other hand, the code might be easier to read if I did:
int ROCK = 0;
int PAPER = 1;
int SCISSORS = 2;
and just used those constants.

Comment: @sixtyfootersdude: The best (language-agnostic) way would probably be to define ROCK = 0, PAPER = 1, and SCISSORS = 2, and then always use these constants.

Comment: If one could downvote a comment...

Comment: @Lord Torgamus: I sereously doubt that there is any shorter implementation than interjay's: (3 + A - B) % 3. :)

Comment: @Andreas: Point taken, I agree.

Comment: @Andreas, at the time I typed my comment, interjay's answer wasn't visible yet.  And yeah, it's pretty good.

Answer (score 88, accepted):

```
winner = (3 + player1 - player2) % 3;
```

This will give 1 if player 1 wins, 2 if player 2 wins, 0 for a tie.

**Explanation**: In the sequence `Rock=0, Paper=1, Scissors=2`, each item defeats the preceding one. This is true even if we treat the sequence as wrapping (that is, the last item precedes the first).

To put this in more mathematical terms, for any item X:

- X is defeated by `(X+1) % 3`.
- X defeats `(X+2) % 3`.

From this, it can be shown that `(3+X-Y) % 3` is 1 if X defeats Y, or 2 if Y defeats X.

Adding 3 is needed to force the result to be non-negative: The modulus of a negative number will be negative or zero in C99 and implementation-dependent in C89.

Comment: This is brilliant, but such a one-liner needs at least 3 lines of documentation.

Comment: +1 Put me in a room with two monkeys and three type writers for all of eternity and we would never come up with that!!!

Comment: I think that c has this kind of construct:

`(3 + player1 - player2) % 3 == 1 ? winner="player1" : (3 + player1 - player2) % 3 == 2? winner="player2" : winner="everyone";`

Comment: Dang!  I thought it might be a modulus, but I made a mistake when I wrote out the table of who wins and it didn't look like it did.  

Anyway, +1 for the tip to add 3, which I wouldn't have known about.

Comment: this is a great answer, except that it is for someone's homework!

Comment: @akf: According to the question, this is just a minor part of the homework, so it's not like I solved someone's assignment for them. Plus, I doubt that the assignment actually required that this be done in a one-liner.

Comment: @afk, we are allowed to use snippets from other sources, as long as we source them.  And yes, it was far from the hardest part of the assignment!

Also, I just realized that rand() % 3 would have been equivalent (i.e., it doesn't matter if the computer picks rock, paper, or scissors, or if it just randomly chooses win, lose, or tie :).