# Rock, Paper, Scissors in Python

Tags: python-3.x

I'm making a rock, paper, scissors game in Python (I'm using Python 33 IDLE) for my Computer Science class. I wrote this script, but when I run it and make my choice it does nothing. Please help and tell me where I'm wrong. Here is the script:

```
from random import choice
cpu = choice(('rock','paper','scissors'))
p1 = input(' rock, paper, or scissors? ')
rock = 1
paper = 2
scissors = 3
if(cpu == rock)and(p1 == rock):
    print('You Tied')
elif(cpu == rock)and(p1 == paper):
    print('You Win')
elif(cpu == rock)and(p1 == scissors):
    print('You Lose')
elif(cpu == paper)and(p1 == rock):
    print('You Lose')
elif(cpu == paper)and(p1 == paper):
    print('You Tied')
elif(cpu == paper)and(p1 == scissors):
    print('You Win')
elif(cpu == scissors)and(p1 == rock):
    print('You Win')
elif(cpu == scissors)and(p1 == paper):
    print('You Lose')
elif(cpu == scissors)and(p1 == scissors):
    print('You Tied')
```

Comment: can you fix your code block - (I can't edit it for you because it's whitespace correction); i.e. there should be no leading whitespace on your "from" import line.

Comment: Edited to improve readability.

Comment: @GiulioMuscarello Well, you could also fix the code while at it.

Comment: @LevLevitsky I don't know Python, I just stumbled upon this question in the review page.

Comment: @GiulioMuscarello I meant what was said in the first comment to this question. Never mind.

Comment: lol thanks guys i've been working on this for 2 days and was really frustrated. we just started python a week ago

Comment: Yep, Stack Overflow is pretty great for this kind of things.

Comment: Also look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2795399/one-liner-to-determine-who-wins-in-rock-paper-scissors. That's in C, but the answer will still work in Python.

Answer (score 1):

Here is your homework for you =P

Some points of errata:

1 - since rock, paper, and scissors are constants and will never change, it's best to follow PEP 8 and write them as all caps.

2 - don't be afraid to use white-space to increase the readability of your code.  Originally you had it all 'globbed together'.  It's nice to read if it's broken up into logical parts (try to read and follow PEP 8 - following the Python style guide will help you IMMENSELY!)

3 - You originally had:

```
cpu = choice(('rock','paper','scissors'))
```

Which makes rock, paper, and scissors `STRINGS` - notice the `''` you put around your options?  If you want to evaluate your randomly picked option you need to instantiate your CONSTANTS first, then have the computer pick from those options - which is why, if you look at my version below, I move your CONSTANTS up above `cpu = choice()`.

4 - It was very _ irritating_ (not your fault, my font's fault) that you had p1... I was reading it pl as in pL... I'd avoid naming variables with numbers in it specifically for this reason.  Instead, I did player_one (the variable name is a bit more descriptive, and it can be more descriptive still, but for this example it's 'good enough').  Again - PEP 8 is your friend!

5 - Good first try!  Welcome to Python!

NB:  I am using 2.6/2.7 Python, not 3.* which is why I have raw_input() instead of your input().

```
from random import choice

ROCK = 1
PAPER = 2
SCISSORS = 3

cpu = choice((ROCK, PAPER, SCISSORS))
player_one = raw_input('-> ROCK, PAPER, or SCISSORS? ')

if str(player_one).upper() == 'ROCK':
    player_one = 1
elif str(player_one).upper() == 'PAPER':
    player_one = 2
elif str(player_one).upper() == 'SCISSORS':
    player_one = 3
else:
    print('What the heck did you pick!?  Pick a valid option!')

if(cpu == ROCK)and(player_one == ROCK):
    print('You Tied')
elif(cpu == ROCK)and(player_one == PAPER):
    print('You Win')
elif(cpu == ROCK)and(player_one == SCISSORS):
    print('You Lose')
elif(cpu == PAPER)and(player_one == ROCK):
    print('You Lose')
elif(cpu == PAPER)and(player_one == PAPER):
    print('You Tied')
elif(cpu == PAPER)and(player_one == SCISSORS):
    print('You Win')
elif(cpu == SCISSORS)and(player_one == ROCK):
    print('You Win')
elif(cpu == SCISSORS)and(player_one == PAPER):
    print('You Lose')
elif(cpu == SCISSORS)and(player_one == SCISSORS):
    print('You Tied')
```

**UPDATE1:**  In response to your latest question, review the following code.  I did a revamp of the code to clean it up. We lost some readability to the "layperson" but once you get used to reading Python I think this is just as clean/clear.  The last two lines of the new code show you one way (of MANY ways) you could achieve your goal.  Keep in mind, you are wanting to convert from int() and str() in the beginning by forcing comparisons.  You didn't have to do this, so I what I did was a compromise:  I created a `tuple` by doing the int() options you had before and combining them with a str() object that is the representation of the int() value.  This way I can swap between the two anytime I want by referencing the index value.

An alternative approach to wanting to print out the results in a string, would be to spend previous line space converting your int()'s back into str() and just do something like:

```
print("You picked " + player_one + " and the CPU picked " + cpu)
```

But, again, you'll have to convert your player_one and cpu integers back into their string.  The method I am using below uses tuples, as I prefer this method over what your knee-jerk reaction wants you to do (which is similar to what you were thinking you might do).

```
from random import choice

ROCK = (1, "ROCK")
PAPER = (2, "PAPER")
SCISSORS = (3, "SCISSORS")

cpu = choice((ROCK, PAPER, SCISSORS))

player_one = raw_input('-> ROCK, PAPER, or SCISSORS? ')

if str(player_one).upper() == 'ROCK':
    player_one = (1, "ROCK")
elif str(player_one).upper() == 'PAPER':
    player_one = (2, "PAPER")
elif str(player_one).upper() == 'SCISSORS':
    player_one = (3, "SCISSORS")
else:
    print('What the heck did you pick!?  Pick a valid option!')

out_vect = (cpu[0], player_one[0])

OUTCOMES = ('You Tied', 'You Win', 'You Lose')
POSSIBILITIES = (([(1,2), (2, 3), (3, 1)], OUTCOMES[1]), ([(2, 1), (3, 2), (1, 3)], OUTCOMES[2]))

if(out_vect[0] == out_vect[1]):
    print OUTCOMES[0]
elif out_vect in POSSIBILITIES[0][0]:
    print(POSSIBILITIES[0][1])
elif out_vect in POSSIBILITIES[1][0]:
    print(POSSIBILITIES[1][1])
else:
    print("~Epic Fail~ in the program!")

result_summary = "You chose " + player_one[1] + " and the CPU chose " + cpu[1]

print result_summary
```

Comment: if that was the solution feel free to mark it as correct by clicking the green check mark next to the top of the response (just move your mouse over it and you'll see an outline for a check mark pop up).  Welcome to StackExchange.

Comment: btw what could i use to have it say "you chose____" and "cpu chose___" under neath you win?

Comment: see my most recent update it provides some more insight to what you are asking.

Answer (score 0):

`cpu` is either `'rock'`, `'paper'` or `'scissors'`, but you compare it only to `1`, `2` and `3`. This is probably the main problem.

You can do `cpu = choice((1, 2, 3))` to fix that.

Or the other way around, compare to string literals, not integers:

```
if cpu == 'rock' and p1 == 'rock': # note the quotes
```

Also, you have three `if`s for a tie, when there should only be one:

```
if cpu == p1:
    print('You tied')
```

Comment: still nothing. its as if its ignoring the if and elif atatements

Comment: @LarryLynnGlasper What do you input for `p1` at the prompt?